# Migrate a change on the inverse property in Core Data

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I need to migrate a version of my Core Data model to a newer version. In the newer version I have added a missing inverse property. The lightweight migration doesn't work in this point. The attribute looses it's one to many related objects.

The migration uses the below code. Is it possible to migrate the change of the inverse property by lightweight or heavyweight migration? Thanks for any hints.[image]

```
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
    initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES)};

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeUrl
                                                    options:options
                                                      error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error persistentStoreCoordinator  %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    NSLog(@"Try to reset persistent store");
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[storeUrl path]
                            error:NULL];
```

Comment: Have you tried using a mapping model?

Comment: @Willeke : thats it. Make it an answer and I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks.